# Possible to Set up Ubuntu Server and run VirtualBox on it

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, virtualbox, nas

I am trying to set up our first home server, as our current NAS is running out of storage.
I bought a physical home server and was thinking about running multiple services on it.
These include TrueNAS, a minecraft server, TS Server and maybe sth else too.
My original idea was to install Ubuntu or Ubuntu Server and set up Virtual Box on it and give TrueNAS and the minecraft server a seperate Virtual maschine.
I tested this on my Windows PC and it worked out pretty nicely.
However, as I am fairly new to Ubuntu, I need to know if this is even possible or if it is easier to simply get Windows Server and execute my plan there.

What do you guys think? Any ideas or comments about my plan (Feel free to call it bullshit but then provide me with a better solution :) ). The server has 64GB of DDR4 RAM, 2 Xeon CPUs and 4 x 4TB HDD and a 960GB SSD (Seagate Ironwolf).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't need a full VM to run a Minecraft server or NAS. Plain old LXD containers will work just as well and use fewer resources. You might not need need TrueNAS at all - Ubuntu has most of what you want already baked in. My own MC server and NAS runs great on quite old, low-power hardware. Testing anything on Windows is not a reliable predictor of how it will work on Ubuntu. THAT's what a VM is good for. Ubuntu is right if you want to learn how it works and have control. Ubuntu is the wrong choice if you want a drop-in replacement for Windows Server or if you are attracted to buzzwords.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox should run on Ubuntu, but Linux provides it's own QEMU-based virtualization, called KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine). It's a native Linux solution, not based on any third-party software like Virtualbox.

For purposes that you describe, it will be probably even better not to use the "full" virtualization with all the overhead of separate virtual machines, but "light" virtualization in form of so called "containers". Containers share the OS, but have separate process spaces, memory spaces etc. This is commonly used in Linux for running separate services each in its own environment. Probably the most popular container solution is Docker, but there are certainly people here who have more knowledge about this type of virtualization than me (I have worked mostly with KVM).